# Позиционирование блоков

Tags: css

Есть три блока div. 
У первого стоит float: left, 
у другого float: right
а третий нужно расположить между ними снизу, как бы в вымышленной третьей колонке. Проблема в том что он выстраивается под вторым блоком так:

```
1     2
      3
```

А нужно так:

```
1     2
   3
```

Так вот, собственно сабж как быть. Не хотелось бы гавнокодить и выравнивать маргинами.
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Спасибо, проблему решил!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без маргинов - никак. =)

```
.b3{clear: both; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
```

clear:both сбросит его вниз, маргины отцентрируют.
Вся беда в том, что блоки с флоатом не "пихают" блоки БЕЗ флоата.

Comment: А почему бы не заменить  

    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
на  

    margin: 0 auto;
Разницы вроде нет, но меньше символов :)

Comment: Разница есть: вы принудительно указали верхний и нижний марджин равными нулю, а это не всегда требуется, особенно при большом числе классов на один элемент или при множественном использовании одного и того же класса.

Comment: Вполне логично. В личном опыта если нужен ненулевой верхний/нижний маржин - указываю его дополнительно.  
Это не критика, всего-лишь размышления :)

Answer (score 0):

Я так сильно не заморачиваюсь. Проще всего использовать тег **table**.
С таблицами работать проще и всегда можно точно знать, что и где будет отображаться. Даже в различных браузерах.